# Unable to add data to databse from models forms django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send data from django forms to backend sqlite3. But I am unable to do so. I am not also getting any error or warning that help me to sort it out.

Here is models.py file

```
from django.db import models
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
    ('Male', 'M'),
    ('Female', 'F')]
class upload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    email=  models.EmailField(max_length=50,null=True)
    file=models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is forms.py file

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import upload
class uploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = upload
        fields = ['name', 'gender', 'phone', 'email','file']
```

Here is view.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import uploadForm
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = uploadForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            form=form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = uploadForm()

    return render(request,'home.html',{'print':form})
```

I am unable to understand where is the issue
This is how template file look like

```
<form  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ print.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT**
This issue is with `FileField`, I removed it, and it start saving in django database. What I want is to save file in media folder and other data in database

I also added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form

Comment: is there any Exception

Comment: no, there is not

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your actually sending anything to the database.

Where is says `form = uploadForm()` you need state you want the posted data to be sent. so this needs to be `form = uploadForm(request.POST)` it should then work I believe. Also when saving the form, remove the `form=form.save()` and leave it as `form.save()`

Try it out and let us know?

Comment: I tried this already, but it did not work. It keep on showing This field is required.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806374/11170350

Comment: Did you add it to the "if" statement or the "else" statement? 
Edit: I think you'll only need it in the if section

Comment: yes, i added it in if statement. and when i print request.POST, i can even see the values entered, but i am unable to save them

Comment: Edit2: Does the table actually show up in the admin panel?

Comment: This issue is with `FileField`, I removed it, and it start saving in django database. What I want is to save file in media folder and other data in database

Comment: I see, just tried it out and got the same result. for the Filefield, are you trying to upload a photo?

Comment: any type of file. as its not ImageField. so expect it to load any file type

Comment: So after a little bit of googling I've found the following link which should help out: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Essentially you need to use 'request.POST' as well as 'request.FILES'
I havne't tried it yet but will do in about an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my post

For handling files, I need to add encryption type to my form as

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Once I added that, to access the files I should use `request.FILES` along with `request.POST`
So now I have this home function in `views.py` file

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = uploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = uploadForm()

    return render(request,'home.html',{'print':form})
```

and my template form looks like

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ print.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Credit : https://youtu.be/Rr1-UTFCuH4?t=244